# How can we get the output fields of a procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have written a procedure but I want to figure out what columns (fields) in the output without running the process?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE! Am I correct in assuming that the procedure is dynamic? Otherwise, you should know what it returns as you wrote it.

Comment: There's no way to do this in a reliable way, since SQL Server allows for things like conditional logic and dynamic SQL in a stored procedure. Just keep that in mind, for whatever method you run into...

Answer (score 3):

Currently you've tagged both [sql-server-2012](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012) and [sql-server-2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008).

If 2012 is correct, you can use [`sp_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql) subject to a few restrictions.

If your procedure is not eligible for `sp_describe_first_result_set` or you are running a version that does not support it, you will have to examine the source code - my preferred method of extracting this is the [`object_definition()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-definition-transact-sql) function, though many people prefer [`sp_helptext`](https://sqlstudies.com/2016/12/21/sp_helptext-vs-object_definition/)

Comment: The sp_describe_first_result_set process can not support dynamic queries.

Answer (score 2):

[OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql) returns a table from an arbitrary query. That query can `exec some_procedure`. The results can be used to define a new table using the `select .. into` syntax. This new table's metadata can be examined to find the definition of the SP's output.

```
drop procedure if exists SomeProc;
go

create or alter procedure SomeProc
as begin
    select
        a = CONVERT(bit, 1),
        b = CONVERT(int, 2)
end
go

drop table if exists SomeTable;
go

select *
into SomeTable 
from openrowset
(
    'SQLNCLI', 
    'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
    'EXEC SomeProc'
);
go

select * from SomeTable;
go

select
    *
from sys.all_columns
where object_id = OBJECT_ID('SomeTable');
```