# Can I return my dynamic sql query into a temp table that can be selected after execution

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to return my dynamic query results into a local or global temp table to be able to manipulate and / join other tables, etc.  I cannot seem to get the results into a temp table.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
--Current Statement--

create table #types (typeid int, prodtype varchar(30), prodgroup varchar(30));
declare @typeid int,
        @sql nvarchar(max)
set @typeid = 0
set @sql = ''
while @typeid < 30
begin
    set @sql = N'select ' +convert(varchar,@typeid) + ' as typeid, global.prodtype' +convert(varchar,@typeid) + ' as SortName, 
        case global.typetogroup' +convert(varchar,@typeid) + '
                when ''0'' then global.typegroup0
                when ''1'' then global.typegroup1
                when ''2'' then global.typegroup2
                when ''3'' then global.typegroup3
                when ''4'' then global.typegroup4
                when ''5'' then global.typegroup5
                when ''6'' then global.typegroup6
                when ''7'' then global.typegroup7
                end as prodgroup
    from Global'
    insert into #types (typeid, prodtype, prodgroup)
    exec sp_sqlexec @sql;
set @typeid = @typeid + 1
end

declare @nse AS nvarchar(max),
        @nsg AS nvarchar(max),
        @sve AS nvarchar(max),
        @svg AS nvarchar(max),
        @fin AS nvarchar(max)

set @nse = (select  substring(
 (select distinct ',' + '[' + #types.prodgroup + ' ' + '- Sales Ex' + ']'
  from #types where prodgroup != '' for xml path('')),2,200000) 
 )
set @nsg = (select  substring(
 (select distinct ',' + '[' + #types.prodgroup + ' ' + '- Sales GST' + ']'
  from #types where prodgroup != '' for xml path('')),2,200000) 
 )
set @sve = (select  substring(
 (select distinct ',' + '[' + #types.prodgroup + ' ' + '- Svc Charge Ex' + ']'
  from #types where prodgroup != '' for xml path('')),2,200000) 
 )
set @svg = (select  substring(
 (select distinct ',' + '[' + #types.prodgroup + ' ' + '- Svc Charge GST' + ']'
  from #types where prodgroup != '' for xml path('')),2,200000) 
 )

--Sales Data--
set @fin = 'select * from (select
Date,
Venue,
Store,
Till,
convert(decimal(18,2),sum(nettsalesex + nettsalesgst)) ''Nett Sales Total'',
convert(decimal(18,2),sum(servicechargeex + servicechargegst)) ''Service Charge Total'',
salesex,
salesgst,
svcchgex,
svcchggst,
convert(decimal(18,2),sum(nettsalesex)) ''nse'',
convert(decimal(18,2),sum(nettsalesgst)) ''nsg'',
convert(decimal(18,2),sum(servicechargeex)) ''sve'',
convert(decimal(18,2),sum(servicechargegst)) ''svg''
from (
select
convert(varchar,transactions.DateTimeTrans,111) ''Date'',
venue.name ''venue'',
store.name ''store'',
workstation.name ''till'',
#types.prodgroup + '' '' + ''- Sales Ex'' ''SalesEx'',
#types.prodgroup + '' '' + ''- Sales GST'' ''SalesGST'',
#types.prodgroup + '' '' + ''- Svc Charge Ex'' ''SvcChgEx'',
#types.prodgroup + '' '' + ''- Svc Charge GST'' ''SvcChgGST'',
case TransLines.TaxType
    when 1 then sum(translines.netttotal - translines.servicecharge) / 1.1
    else 0
end ''NettSalesEx'',
case TransLines.TaxType
    when 1 then sum(translines.netttotal - translines.servicecharge) - (sum(translines.netttotal - translines.servicecharge) / 1.1) 
    else 0
end ''NettSalesGST'',
case TransLines.TaxType
    when 1 then sum(translines.servicecharge) / 1.1
    else 0
end ''ServiceChargeEx'',
case TransLines.TaxType
    when 1 then sum(translines.servicecharge) - (sum(translines.servicecharge) / 1.1)
    else 0
end ''ServiceChargeGST''
from transactions
join translines on translines.TransactionID = Transactions.TransactionID
join #types on #types.typeid = translines.ProdType
join Workstation on Workstation.WorkstationID = transactions.TillID
join store on store.storeid = workstation.storeid
join venue on venue.venueid = store.VenueID
where shiftid >= 67049  and
transactions.transType not in (-1,0,257,293,324,325,533,534,32770,32771,32772,32773,32774,16404,16402,16403,16418,16419,16420,16443,16444,16445,16446,16417,16447,16448,16449)
group by venue.name,
store.name,
workstation.name,
translines.ProdType,
translines.TaxType,
#types.prodgroup + '' '' + ''- Sales Ex'',
#types.prodgroup + '' '' + ''- Sales GST'',
#types.prodgroup + '' '' + ''- Svc Charge Ex'',
#types.prodgroup + '' '' + ''- Svc Charge GST'',
convert(varchar,transactions.DateTimeTrans,111))d group by date,
venue,
store,
till,
salesex,
salesgst,
svcchgex,
svcchggst) e
pivot 
(
    sum(nse) for salesex in (' + @nse + ')
) P1
pivot 
(
    sum(nsg) for salesgst in (' + @nsg + ')
) P2
pivot 
(
    sum(sve) for svcchgex in (' + @sve + ')
) P3
pivot
(
    sum(svg) for svcchggst in (' + @svg + ')
) P4'

exec sp_sqlexec @fin

drop table #types
```

Comment: You say you want to manipulate the table populated by the dynamic query or join other tables to it, but how would you work with such a table if its columns are dynamic? That would probably require making all the manipulation and joins dynamic too, no? This might have a viable solution but I suspect the likelihood would depend on what specifically you were going to do with the pivoted set. Perhaps you could do the manipulation/joins first and the (dynamic) pivoting last, directly returning the pivoted results to the client (assuming that's the goal)?

Answer (score 0):

Create the temp table of the structure you need before execution.

```
CREATE TABLE #Result (
Date    <type of the column>,
Venue   <type of the column>,
Store   <type of the column>,
Till    <type of the column>,
/* and so on */
);

/* make your dynamic query */

INSERT #Result
exec sp_sqlexec @fin
```

Comment: If you don't fancy doing the legwork to figure out the DDL for `#Result`, you could use the `OPENROWSET` technique described [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/241332/68127) to figure out what the required column names & types will be for the target. Protip: wrap the whole mess into `create proc foo ...` to make the `OPENROWSET` syntax easier.

Comment: Would recommend replacing sp_sqlexec with sp_executesql - sp_sqlexec is very old and whilst it is still around (likely for backwards compatibility purposes) it is now not documented.

Comment: The temp table structure is not known before the execution of the statement.  The statement itself is returning dynamically the columns in the table when the query executes.  What might work but I couldn't find it, was the ability to look at the results of the query and then put them through into a temp table.  Similarly to how you can look at tempdb schema and query temp db column names, etc

Comment: If so, you should pay attention on Peter's comment and especially on the link there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can add `IF` your own query. Like this:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##types') IS NULL 
BEGIN
    set @sql = N'
    select top 10 NameSurName,Mail,Phone
    INTO ##types 
    from Customer'
    exec sp_sqlexec @sql
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    set @sql = N'
    select top 10 NameSurName,Mail,Phone
    from Customer'
    insert into ##types 
    exec sp_sqlexec @sql
END
```